# How to parse timezone data?

Tags: python, timezone

There has been a recent issue with the timezone data with a claim from some company that claim to has been violated, so IANA has taken it upon themselves to provide the timezone data.

Now the problem is that data hosted [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), isn't in a format I can parse easily is there something missing here or do I need to formulate the data to be usable myself, or is there some format that are providing that I am clearly not seeing.

I am used to seeing  .csv or .tvs or .xls

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to properly store this data so it can be used to build libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the `pytz` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The fields are tab separated.** There are `Zone` and `Rule` fields. Lines beginning with a `#` being comments.

### Zone field format

```
# Zone  NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
```

### Rule field format

```
# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  TYPE    IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
```

TSV (or CSV) parsers in Python will be able to parse it.